# How does SCCM 2012 capture an image?

Tags: windows-7, imaging, sccm-2012-r2

I have set up a task sequence in SCCM to capture an image from an existing machine.  The task sequence works fine, but there are a few things I don't understand.  When it captures the image, there are two different partitions: one 300 MB partition and the other varies depending on the size of the image.  What exactly is on that 300 MB partition?  Also, after the image is captured, I am forced to set up Windows again on the machine where the image has been captured.  Why exactly is this?  Can someone just give a basic rundown of what exactly is happening when you capture an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source machine probably has two partitions - windows by default sets up a 300MB partition for boot files.  It doesn't have a drive letter, but you can see it in disk management.

The reason you had to set it up again is because the capture ran sysprep.  This reinitializes parts of windows and get its ready to be used on new hardware.  Beware - there is a limit to how many times sysprep can be run before it starts causing issues (mostly with activation).